# Display Currency with all decimals intact in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need to display the currency format with all the decimal places intact.

If the value for amount is: `123456.789`
The Output should be `1,23,456.789 $`

> if I write `{{amount | currency:$}}` Output is: `1,23,456.78 $` [removes last digit]
>
> If I write `{{amount | currency:$:3}}`,  Output is: `1,23,456.78 $` [it displays as expected]

But the problem is I can not fix the number of decimals as it keeps changing.

Answer (score 1):

Got the resolution. Implemented following custom filter(currency symbol was not mandatory :) )

```
myApp.filter('customNumber', function($filter) {
    var standardNumFilterFn = $filter('number');
    return function(num) {
        if(num){
            var numSplit = (''+num).split('.');
            if(numSplit && numSplit[1]){
                return standardNumFilterFn(num, (''+numSplit[1]).length);
            }
            return standardNumFilterFn(num, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

and then:

```
{{amount | customNumber}}
```